# Relay pin acts differently with load

Tags: arduino

I have the following code.

```
 void setup(){
    pinMode(14, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(14, HIGH); //Relay
 }
 void loop(){
    if (!digitalRead(14)){
       digitalWrite(10,HIGH); //LED
       digitalWrite(11,LOW);  //LED
    }else{
       digitalWrite(10, LOW);
       digitalWrite(11, HIGH);
    }
 }
```

In another portion of the code the relay pin changes states and I'm monitoring that with the `digitalRead` portion in the loop in hopes of changing which led is on based on the state.

Now the hard part. All of that works, except when I wire the relay to a magnet.  This is all for a very intricate door control system with maglocks.  And for some reason with the maglock hooked up to the relay the Arduino behaves very differently.  It slows to a crawl once the relay is changed.  Up until then all is fine, but as soon as the relay is activated, something causes it to slow way down.

What I can't figure out is why all is fine and relay triggers without side affects, until a load is attached to it.

Any ideas? Or a better way of monitoring a relay state? (Without storing its pseudo value in a variable)

Answer (score 1):

You set the pin 14 as `OUTPUT`, but you're trying to read from it with `digitalRead`.

What you want to know is the value of the register that stores the value of the port.

You could go the easy way and use an auxiliar variable that stores the pin state like this:

```
bool state = true;
void setup(){
  pinMode(14, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(14, state); //Relay
}

void loop(){
  if (!state){
    digitalWrite(10,HIGH); //LED
    digitalWrite(11,LOW);  //LED
  }else{
    digitalWrite(10, LOW);
    digitalWrite(11, HIGH);
  }
}
```

And edit the rest of the code accordingly so `state` changes accordingly.

The 'Hardest to understand' solution, is to read the register value. since you're using pin 14 (the same as pin A0) you have to look into the port C According to the Arduino Reference on port manipulation (Link at the end of my answer).
So you can just do this:

```
void setup(){
  pinMode(14, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(14, HIGH); //Relay
}

void loop(){
  if (!BitRead(PORTC,0)){  //Reads bit 0 of the register of PORTC (wich is the state of pin14)
    digitalWrite(10,HIGH); //LED
    digitalWrite(11,LOW);  //LED
  }else{
    digitalWrite(10, LOW);
    digitalWrite(11, HIGH);
  }
}
```

This solution is more elegant and is exactly what you need. It might be harder to come up with so if you don't remember this in the future you could always use the "state" variable method.

Reference [Bit Read Operation](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/bits-and-bytes/bitread/) and [Arduino Reference on port manipulation](https://docs.arduino.cc/hacking/software/PortManipulation) for more information.

Comment: This looks great and I will try it.   But how do you know 14 is A0 and that corresponds to C0?  I read the page you provided and don't see how you're translating pin 14 to that.  This Arduino is a Mega, if that changed anything.

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup You can google "Arduino Uno pinout" and there are also pin names like `PC0`, which means `PORTC` for outputs or enabling pull-ups, `PINC` for reading actual inputs and `DDRC` for direction. You can find all the details in `ATMega328p` datasheet

Comment: In the link I gave it's all you need: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/PortManipulation

I quote: "PORTC maps to Arduino analog pins 0 to 5." and "For a complete mapping of Arduino pin numbers to ports and bits, see the diagram for your chip: ATmega8, ATmega168. (Note that some bits of a port may be used for things other than i/o; be careful not to change the values of the register bits corresponding to them.)"

So you can follow the link to your chip version or you can even google it as @KIIV said.